# Read specified lines in file - BASH

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

I would like to read specified lines in file **iptables**. I want to read lines started with **:** and ends with **space**.

File iptables

```
 # Generated by iptables 04:13:50 2015
 *filter
 :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
 :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
 :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]


-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport http --dport 1024: -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport https --dport 1024: -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport webcache --dport 1024: -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMIT
# Completed on Mon Dec 04:13:50 2015
```

My **output** should be like.

```
INPUT
FORWARD
OUTPUT
```

How can I do that? I was thinking about `sed` and `IFS` but I do not have idea how.

I got output look like this

```
13:50  
INPUT
0]
FORWARD
0]
OUTPUT
0]
13:50
```

after executed:

```
grep -Po ':\K[^ ]*' file
```

I want omit `13:50` and `0]` and other related things.

My goal is to have output where are only **names of chains**.

Comment: Did you mean "My ***output*** should be like." ??

Comment: Yes sure. Overworked.

Comment: Please include the command that gave the output in the edited question.  Also, what is the input?  Where do `13:50` and `0]` come from?

Comment: @MichalN. yes, you can (and should) edit your question but i) please don't add "edit"; these questions will remain here for ever and the next user to have the same problem doesn't need to know what was in the original question and what wasn't. ii) show us the _exact_ input you need to parse. Your edit shows that your example wasn't representative of your actual input. We can't help you if you don't show us what you need to parse. iii) show us what you ran to get the output in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another `sed`:

```
sed -ne's/^:\([[:upper:]]*\).* $/\1/p' <in >out
```

This command attempts to do one `s///`ubstitution per input line. Unless it is successful, `-n`othing is `p`rinted to output. So the *`/regexp/`* must match a line and the `s///`ubstitution must take place before `sed` will `p`rint anything, because its only `p`rint command is a *flag* on the `s///`ubstitution statement.

In order to match an input line must first match a `:` colon at the `^` head of the line, immediately followed by `*` zero or more `[[:upper:]]`-cased alphabetic characters, then followed by `*` zero or more of any other kind of `.` character, which must last be followed by at least one space at the `$` tail of the line.

When it does match the sequence of `[[:upper:]]`-chars which are referenced in the `\(` sub group `\)` is used to replace the entire line as saved in `\1`.

But that doesn't work for your example input because your example starts with a space and ends without one. A regexp that will work for your example:

```
sed -ne's/^ *:\([[:upper:]]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Which is mostly the same but instead of looking for a definite space at the tail of the line it looks for any number of spaces at the head.

---

```
INPUT
FORWARD
OUTPUT
```

Comment: Could you explain command please? It works great.

Comment: @MichalN - done.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use `grep`:

```
grep -Po '^ *:\K[^ ]*' file
```

Explanation:

- `-P`: use perl compatible regular expressions
- `-o`: print only matched parts
- `\K`: cut everything matched so far
- `[^ ]*`: match everything but space zero or more times

Output:

```
INPUT
FORWARD
OUTPUT
```

Comment: Thank you. And how to omit following stuff?
`13:50
blah
0]
yoyo
0]
bluu
0]
13:50`
I want omit 0] and 13:50

Comment: @MichalN. It already omits all stuff starting from space. That's what an option `-o` is for.

Comment: Please check mentioned stuff again. I pressed enter meanwhile I was typing.

Comment: updated question

Comment: @MichalN. see the edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

To do this with `sed`:

```
sed -n '             # -n do not print lines to output by default
    /^:.* $/ {       # address lines beginning with colon, ending with space
        s/^://       # remove colon at beginning of line
        s/ .*//      # remove first space and everything following
        p            # print the edited line
    }
'
```

Comment: @MichalN. If one of these answers solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @terdon ok, can I edit question as I did?